# Having two SQL Server related tables, select complete rows of one and partial of other

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS Access was very easy to acomplish but I'm having troubles with SQL Server

I have this query:

```
SELECT        Organigrama.Item, Organigrama.Id, Organigrama.ParentItem, Rol_Menu.Cod_Rol
FROM            Rol_Menu RIGHT JOIN
                         Organigrama ON Rol_Menu.Cod_Menu = Organigrama.Id
WHERE        (Rol_Menu.Cod_Rol = '5')
```

The purpose is to get all the items of `Organigrama` and the elements in common with `Rol_Menu.Col_Rol` appears with 5, the others with Null

I need to fill a menu structure into a treeview [image]
When the user select another Rol just get nodes checked that rol have access to
im determining if in the row the `Col_Rol` isn't null so the query I need to get 
something like this:

> Item | Id  |  ParentItem | Cod_Rol
>   A    | 3   |  null | 5
>   B    | 4   |  A    | 5
>   C    | 5   |  A    | null
>   D    | 6   |  B    | 5 
>   E    | 7   |  C    | null
>   F    | 8   |  E    | null
>
> [image]

Comment: maybe i'm bad with the logic, but i did it in acces, get all of table A and some of table B

Comment: @CesarRomeroo - can u put your tables here ? just a sample and tell us the output you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to include the extra restriction in the join criteria rather then the where clause. The criteria are evaluated before the outer join adds the null columns. The where clause is evaluated afterwards, and eliminates the nulls.

```
select
    Organigrama.Item, 
    Organigrama.Id, 
    Organigrama.ParentItem, 
    Rol_Menu.Cod_Rol
from
    Rol_Menu 
        right join
    Organigrama 
        on Rol_Menu.Cod_Menu = Organigrama.Id and
           Rol_Menu.Cod_Rol = '5'
```

either that or add `or Rol_Menu.Cod_Rol is null` to the end of the where clause.